# SELECT statements as INSERT parameters along with other parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Both of the SELECT statements return only one scalar data each. I wish to pass them as the first two parameters of the INSERT statement. But it's throwing an error stating invalid comma after the second SELECT statement. What am I doing wrong here?

```
INSERT INTO messages(src_id, tar_id, body, time)
         SELECT id FROM chatters WHERE (uname = 'adnan'),
       SELECT id FROM chatters WHERE (uname = 'john'), 'Hello John', '1971-12-16';
```

Comment: If the user names do not exist, do you want a row inserted with `NULL` values or do you want no row inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole `SELECT` in brackets:

```
INSERT INTO messages(src_id, tar_id, body, time)
   VALUES
  ( ( SELECT id FROM chatters WHERE (uname = 'adnan') ),
   ( SELECT id FROM chatters WHERE (uname = 'john') ),
   'Hello John',
   '1971-12-16' );
```

Comment: Error:  Comma after the second bracket after 'adnan'

Comment: Sorry forgot `VALUES`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `insert into .. select` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO messages(src_id, tar_id, body, time)
   SELECT max(case when uname = 'adnan' then id end),
          max(case when uname = 'john' then id end),
          'Hello John',
          '1971-12-16'
     FROM chatters 
    where uname in ('adnan','john');
```

Comment: Sorry If I didn't make it clear. The last two parameters of the INSERT statements should be independent, not related to the SELECT statement. Does your code acknowledge that?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Comment: You could also use FILTER, to avoid the CASE: MAX(id) FILTER(WHERE uname = 'adnan')